# Cucumber throws Exception when I use lookarounds in step definitions

Tags: regex, cucumber

I have the following step in cucumber:

```
 @And("^(?:.*) sees that client price of (?!product).* \"(.*)\" equals (.*) (.*)$")
```

When a test runs with the following sentence:
And director sees that client price of room "Double" equals EUR 411.60
I get this error:

```
ava.util.NoSuchElementException
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.TreeRegexp$IntRange.next(TreeRegexp.java:99)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.TreeRegexp$IntRange.next(TreeRegexp.java:82)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.GroupBuilder.build(GroupBuilder.java:18)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.GroupBuilder.build(GroupBuilder.java:21)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.TreeRegexp.match(TreeRegexp.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.Argument.build(Argument.java:12)
    at io.cucumber.cucumberexpressions.RegularExpression.match(RegularExpression.java:54)
    at io.cucumber.stepexpression.StepExpression.match(StepExpression.java:22)
    at io.cucumber.stepexpression.ExpressionArgumentMatcher.argumentsFrom(ExpressionArgumentMatcher.java:21)
```

Why is that so? What can I do to avoid this error?

Comment: This appears to be a [known issue with Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/510), but perhaps it has been fixed in the latest version.

Comment: Having finally updated cucumber I see that you're right. This step works okay in the new version. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that.  Your regex is totally valid BTW, assuming the Java regex engine is what is running it.